# Powershell HasUniqueRoleAssignments to check if subsites have unique permissions.

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am writing a script to check if each site/subsite has unique or inherited permissions. I am having an issue where HasUniqueRole is not doing what it is supposed to do, it just returns true or false but when I write it to host, nothing is printed. Any ideas why this isn't functioning properly or does it need to be loaded in first? If I put it into an if else statement, it prints that any website has inherited permissions.

```
$site = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter website URL"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site -UseWebLogin
$currentSubwebs = Get-PnPSubwebs -Recurse

foreach ($currentSubweb in $currentSubWebs) {
            $subWebTitle = $currentSubWeb.Title
            Write-Host $subWebTitle -ForegroundColor Red
            $subSiteURL = $currentSubweb.Url
            Write-Host $subSiteURL -ForegroundColor Green


            Write-Host $currentSubweb.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
}
```

Comment: When you call `Get-PnPSubwebs` there is an `-Includes` parameter. Can you include `HasUniqueRoleAssignments`. Example: `$currentSubwebs = Get-PnpSubwebs -Recurse -Includes HasUniqueRoleAssignments`

Comment: That worked, thank you! I've been tying to figure this out for the last two hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$currentSubwebs = Get-PnPSubwebs -Recurse
```

to

```
$currentSubwebs = Get-PnpSubwebs -Recurse -Includes HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```